# what is the best way to implement runtime check of shared library version?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, cross-platform

I'm developing a cross-platform application that uses few shared libraries (also developed by me). I need to ensure that application is loading correct versions of that libraries at runtime. i.e. if user has specified path to some old version of shared library in config file application has to be able to detect this fact, do some logging and terminate. What is the best way to implement this? I'm sure that this problem is not new and there has to be some standart, "best-practice" solution.

The one solution I can think of is following:

1. Use version.h files in app and libs, during build step write same version values to both version.h files.
2. Implement getVersion() method in library, which will be used by application after loading library to ensure that library has expected version.

Any alternatives?